# UIViews with ambiguous height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a collection view inside of a UIView. I need to have the collection view communicate to the UIView the height it should be depending on the amount of content inside the collection view.

[image: Imgur]

I need to then let this UiView (white box) know how tall it should be. I believe I did this part correctly in my setup function, but I'm not certain (I'm new to coding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to have the collection view communicate to the UIView the height it should be depending on the amount of content inside the collection view

That height is the layout's `collectionViewContentSize` height. But note that this height can grow beyond the size of the window, since this is a scroll view - the whole point is that the size of the content can be greater than the size of the collection view. Thus it might be better to ask yourself *why* you think you need to do this.

Comment: I'm using a scroll view in a different view (above is a subview). You are correct - The content can be greater in size than the collection view, and I'm not really sure how to determine the height the collection view should be to fit all content returned from the server, which in return tells the subview the height it should be to fit the size of the collection view, then this UIView tells the subview in another view controller how tall it should be, which then needs to tell the scroll view in the main view controller how to adjust itself to fit this newly sized subview.

Comment: "and I'm not really sure how to determine the height the collection view should be to fit all content returned from the server" That's what I just told you — the _layout_ does that.

Comment: So the collection view automatically determines the size it needs to be?

Comment: Noooooo, the collection view's layout automatically determines the size its _content_ needs to be. The collection view is a scroll view. Its content size can be bigger than its own size. That is what scrolling _is_. The collection view's _own_ size is up to _you_. I believe you are just making me repeat myself... All of this is contained in my answer. Did you _read_ it?

Comment: I apologize - I am very, very new to coding. I've been coding for about two months now. I understand what you're saying. I'll keep learning and I will ask better questions.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question, but you need to think about the answers you get! In my opinion, the real point of my answer is actually the last sentence. Since the content of the collection view is going to be scrollable, it seems _pointless_ to size something else in relation to the _content_. Just size your collection view itself in terms of its _surroundings_ and stop.

Comment: I completely get what You're saying. The collection view itself is a scrollable "window", so why not just make it the size it needs to be and then stop. I think I am misunderstanding what I need to achieve what I would like to do. I'm creating a user profile that has a feed and I need to push up the user profile to use more of the screen to view the content inside the collection view.

Comment: You have understood perfectly. But now I don't understand your next problem: "I'm creating a user profile that has a feed and I need to push up the user profile to use more of the screen to view the content inside the collection view" Do you simply mean you want the collection view, which is a scroll view, _to scroll_? Then consult the UIScrollView documentation!

Comment: Do you use twitter? The twitter "me" section is exactly what I'm trying to do, just not with a tableview.

Comment: No, I don't see what you mean. The Twitter "me" section simply _is_ a table view - the table view doesn't change size, it simply sits there occupying the _whole interface_. And indeed, that is the normal thing for a collection view as well. Thus, I don't see at this point why your question involves changing the size of _anything_.